# Deleting a range of records in a table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have around 1176 genuine records in a table, but I need to delete records in the table from row 1177 to 7428. How can I write a DELETE statement that will leave me with only the beginning 1176 records?

Comment: Is there a table ID or date or some other ordered thing that you can use to distinguish between the 'genuine' records and the 'other' records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it by id

```
DELETE FROM table_y WHERE id>1176
```

backup your table

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your table is using a auto incremented primary key (let's say `somePrimaryKey`):

```
DELETE myTable
WHERE ROWNUM > 1176
ORDER BY somePrimaryKey;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete everything that has a higher ID then the highest of which you want to keep.

```
delete from `tablename` where `row_id` > 1176
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
DELETE FROM table_Name WHERE id >= 1176 && id <=7428 ;
```